# Where can I find node.js interpreter

Tags: node.js, webstorm

In WebStorm to get `karma.conf` running I need to configure it in a pop up window and enter the "path to the node.js interpreter".

*(for some reason this information vanished after a restart)*

**Questions:**

1. What is the path to the needed file?
2. Where is the node interpreter on Mac/Linux/Windows by default?

(I am on OS X)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Generally, on OSX and Linux, you can find any program with `which program`. In your case, type

```
which node
```

in terminal.

Comment: whereis command can be used if it's available. http://www.computerhope.com/unix/uwhereis.htm

Answer (score 27):

On windows command prompt

```
where node
```

Answer (score 7):

On OSX if you've installed Node.js with brew:

`/usr/local/bin/node`

You can check the exact folder on your machine with the command `which node`

**Important**

When the finder opens on OSX, you won't be able to navigate to this path initially. You'll first need to navigate to the root folder e.g. `Macintosh HD` and then perform the keyboard shortcut `Command + Shift + .` (. = dot = period) to be able to select hidden files and folders.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install nodejs

whereis nodejs

nodejs: /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/nodejs /usr/include/nodejs /usr/share/nodejs /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz
```

Configuring NodeJS Intepreter in IntelliJ:

```
File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM
Node interpreter: Add... (select from the above path or add it)
/usr/bin/nodejs
```

Then, click on `Enable` button and select the modules.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX:

`/usr/local/bin/node`

*well I got it by myself, but wanted to share the answer, as I couldn't find it on google / stack overflow and hope to save somebody some time*

Comment: You could always find it out by typing 'which nodejs' (or 'which node' in your terminal. And it even works on Windows!

Comment: afaik 'which' works not on windows. Do you mean maybe on windows in a linux-shell? If yes, this could be edited in the accepted answer for the windows users

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful for someone. I tried all the previous methods on Linux Ubuntu 19.10, none worked, neither reinstalling nodejs. So I installed Webstorm via snap, with:

```
sudo snap install webstorm
sudo snap install webstorm --classic
```

And surprise, Nodejs was already configured in this version. Then I erased the webstorm version that I installed from Ubuntu Softwared. 
That worked for me and was easy. Hope that can give you a clue.

Comment: thanks for the update :) Meanwhile I'm also on Ubuntu and "manually" installed node, because of the version-problems with the Ubuntu repositories: In my `home` I created an `applications` folder and unzipped the latest node there. Then I can sym-link all binaries in `~/.bin` to have them in PATH (see https://askubuntu.com/a/60221/299951)

Comment: Your welcome! I considered to do the same but I also had problems with sync (for my settings and plugins) and couldn't find a solution for that. With snap that worked fine and also the interpreter. Thank you for your solution, it might be helpful in a future.